# What does ruby -run do? How does it work?

Tags: ruby

I've seen this used to start a process:

```
ruby -run
```

What does it do?

Where is the documentation located?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a little misleading in appearance... The flag isn't `-run` as in the verb *run*, but rather `-r` to require [the `un.rb` file](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/un.rb) from the standard library, which [according to documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/un/rdoc/un_rb.html), contains:

> Utilities to replace common UNIX commands in Makefiles etc

The `-r<libraryname>` flag allows you to `require` a library from the command line before your program's execution begins.

See `ruby --help` for the command line flags (I suspect you already did).

Comment: Ha. I would have never figured that out. I did `man ruby` but didn't think to look for `-r`.

Comment: In the `--help` it's hard to spot too, because the option is described as "`-rlibrary require the library before executing your script`"

Comment: The documentation [used to be much better](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/un/rdoc/Object.html) but for some reason is much more limited post-2.0. Nevertheless you can still run `ruby -run -e help` for a synopsis.

Comment: Way back when RubyGems first started and was a separate third-party project, they pulled the same trick by providing a file named `ubygems.rb`, which allowed you to say `ruby -rubygems` if you wanted to use Gems.

Comment: Why reimplement `rm`, `cp`, etc. in Ruby? What's the point? Most of it are just proxies to a `FileUtils` method? What am I missing here?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Not all Operating Systems have them, so if you want to write a portable `Makefile`, you need to take care of that. If you write a portable `Makefile` for a YARV C extension, then you already know you have Ruby available, but you don't know whether you have POSIX utilities available.